# VB.NET: How to initialize and show a WPF window in a single-line lambda statement?

Tags: vb.net

I want to reduce these 5 ugly lines:

```
    Dim newMenuItem As New MenuItem
    AddHandler newMenuItem.Click, Sub()
                                      Dim a As New wSomeWindow
                                      a.Show()
                                  End Sub
```

into 2 to make the code nice and clean. Is that possible?

I found this oneliner:

```
   (new Form2()).Show();
```

but don't know how to translate it into VB and incorporate it into the existing code.

Comment: New wSomeWindow().Show maybe.

Comment: @CruleD That throws a syntax error on New.

Comment: Sub() (new wsomewindow).show() is my guess

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is

```
 Dim f As New Form2
 f.Show()
```

or

```
Using f As New Form2
    f.Show()
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with a shared function, e.g.

```
Public Shared Function(Of TWindow As {Window, New}) CreateMenuItemForWindow() As MenuItem

    Dim retval As New MenuItem
    AddHandler retval.Click, Sub()
                                 Dim wnd As New TWindow
                                 wnd.Show()
                             End Sub

    Return retval
End Function
```

I might be missing parens on the `New` constraint.  This would let you do something like:

```
Dim newMenuItem = CreateMenuItemForWindow(Of wSomeWindow)()
```

I considered trying to tweak this to get deduction of the type argument, but I think this way of doing it is more clear and straightforward.